# How to add home button using jquery-mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

By default jquery-mobile adds a back button on each page after main page. I wish to know how can I add the home button also ?
Here is an example: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a1/#experiments/api-viewer/index.html

Note: This link is only good for firefox/chrome

Thanks.

Comment: your link points to 1.0alpha1. Just so that you know - latest release is alpha3 and if you use any reference or tutorials - those for alpha1 are incompatible.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Without modifying the jquery-mobile.js source code, the only way I can think to do it, is to add your own navigation links to the header.  Once you add your own link, the automatic 'Back' button will disappear, so we will create 2 links, one for back, and one for home.

You will notice page 2 and 3 both have back buttons and a home button and you can either go back or jump directly to home.  This requires you to modify the 'header' section for each page, but its not that big of a deal since its always the same (copy and paste) no modification needed per instance.

The 'home' link will be in the top right (as per the default behavior of a second link it to put it top right).

Here is the example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div data-role="page" id="firstpage">

        <div data-role="header">
                <h1>First Page</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
                <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>
                <p>View internal page called <a href="#secondpage">second page</a></p>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="secondpage">

        <div data-role="header">
                <a href='#' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon='arrow-l' onclick="history.back(); return false">Back</a><h1>Bar</h1><a href="#firstpage">home</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
                <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page. (this is secondpage)</p>
                <p><a href="#thirdpage">Go to third page</a></p>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="thirdpage">

        <div data-role="header">
                <a href='#' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon='arrow-l' onclick="history.back(); return false">Back</a><h1>Bar</h1><a href="#firstpage">home</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
                <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.  (this is thirdpage)</p>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

If you wanted to make it do it automatically, you could also just hack the js...

Right after this piece of code (around line 1084 of the non minified jquery.mobile-1.0a2.js)

```
$( "<a href='#' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon='arrow-l'>"+ o.backBtnText +"</a>" )
                                                .click(function() {
                                                        history.back();
                                                        return false;
                                                })
                                                .prependTo( $this );
```

Add a line like this, where #firstpage is the id of your home page, I couldn't find a way to reference the home page without calling it by name, feel free to improve.. I didn't want to do / or just # won't work...  but this method works

```
$( "<a href='#firstpage' class='ui tn-right'>Home</a>" ).appendTo( $this );
```

Answer (score 23):

There's a simpler solution: just add a link to your header div with `class="ui-btn-right"`. This is essential so that the jQuery Mobile back button can be automatically added to the left. There's also a few other data-* attributes that you can use so you can use the built-in theme icon etc, as shown:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <a href="/" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" 
           data-direction="reverse">Home</a> 
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        ...
```

(Obviously change the home href URL to something sensible for your environment, don't just use "/" because it limits where your app can be deployed.)

Comment: if you set the `href` to the same url as the home url, it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

```
<div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar">
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <a href="Main.html" data-role="button" rel=external><img src="/MobileTest/images/Home.png" /> </a>
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button" rel=external><img src="/MobileTest/images/MyShare.png" /></a>
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button" rel=external><img src="/MobileTest/images/SharedWithMe.png" /></a>
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button" rel=external><img src="/MobileTest/images/settings.png" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You could use `rel=external` in you `href` tag. This will open the homepage without a back button.

Answer (score 1):

When first using jqm to develop an application, I wanted both home and back buttons on the top header because the navigation tree is deep.  Using the core button classes such as "ui-btn-right" or "ui-btn-left" work great-- IF you only want one button on each side.

But if you are like me and want two buttons on the left, you can use a little custom CSS and positioning to get it where you want.  I also wrapped the buttons in a custom-header class, as well as use CSS to control the title in the header. You will need the place each button on a different z-index, otherwise each button will conflict with the other.

This is the header:

```
    <div id="home-btn" class="header-btn-left-pos1">
        <a href="config.html" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-rel="home">Home</a>
    </div><!-- /home-btn -->

    <div id="back-btn" class="header-btn-left-pos2">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-rel="back">Back</a>
    </div><!-- /back-btn -->

    <div class="header-title" align="center">
        <h4>Business Locations</h4>
    </div><!-- /header-title -->

</div><!-- /custom header -->
```

This is the CSS:

```
.custom-header
{
    height:18px;
}
.header-title
{
    position:relative;
    top:-10px;
}
.header-btn-left-pos1
{
    position:absolute;
    left:25px;
    top:5px;
    z-index:1;
}
.header-btn-left-pos2
{
    position:absolute;
    left:105px;
    top:5px;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Hope this gives you more options.